# Is there a way to combine functions for this simple task?

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie and was wondering, instead of writing this on two separate lines like I have here, can I combine the `innerHTML` and `style` properties together on one line? Or is there a more concise way of writing this?

I know this is a poor example and would  never actually be used, I'm just trying to figure out if there's a way to combine the `innerHTML` and `style` (or whatever functions) into one line instead of having two `document.getElementById`'s.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'Show this text';
  document.getElementById('test').style = 'display:block';
}
```

```css
#test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` and `style` are both properties of an element, not methods. Most methods you can chain, however. But you won't get less than two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing right basically, however you can call `document.getElementById` only once:

```js
const testElement = document.getElementById('test');
testElement.innerHTML='Show this text';
testElement.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the return of the element by

```
ele = document.getElementById('test')
```

then

```
ele.innerHTML='Show this text';
ele.style='display:block';
```

But regarding your question, no, not without recreating the element what I know of

Answer (score 0):

You can clean it up a bit by storing the result of `getElementById` in a variable and using the `hidden` attribute ([browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=hidden), can be polyfills exist for browsers that don’t support it):

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
    const test = document.getElementById('test');
    test.textContent = 'Show this text';
    test.hidden = false;
}
</script>

<p id="test" hidden></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```